# How to enable natural scrolling for GNOME terminal in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, touchpad, gnome-terminal, scrolling

I'm newbie to Ubuntu, freshly installed 14.04 on Dell Inspiron laptop.

I enabled '**two finger scrolling**' and '**natural scrolling**' from 'Mouse and Touchpad' settings. Natural scrolling with two-finger scroll works fine in many apps like File browser, Internet browsers etc. However it's **not working in GNOME Terminal(3.6.2)**, the scrolling action is still opposite to 'natural scrolling'.

Did I miss toggling few other settings? I researched quite a few questions on the forum, but nothing specific has come for GNOME Terminal.

Comment: 16.04 will be out in less than a month. I strongly advise you to upgrade. It's a much newer system, including bugfixes of the last 2 years, among others more than a hundred fixes to gnome-terminal, and in particular I confirm that toggling 'natural scrolling' effects gnome-terminal as desired.

Comment: @egmont Oh, that's good news! Thanks for sharing, Is 16.04 an LTS release?

Comment: Yes, <even>.04 are LTS releases.